# Reading results of gurobi optimisation ("results.sol") in new python script

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am trying to run a rolling horizon optimisation where I have multiple optimisation scripts, each generating their own results. Instead of printing results to screen at every interval, I want to write each of the results using model.write("results.sol") - and then read them back into a results processing script (separate python script).

I have tried using read("results.sol") using Python, but the file format is not recognised. Is there any way that you can read/process the .sol file format that Gurobi outputs? It would seem bizarre if you cannot read the .sol file at some later point and generate plots etc.

Maybe I have missed something blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to answer without seeing your code as we have to guess what you are doing.

But well...

When you use

```
model.write("out.sol")
```

Gurobi will use it's own format to write it (and what is written is inferred from the file-suffix).

This can easily be read by:

```
model.read("out.sol")
```

If you used

```
x = read("out.sol")
```

you are using python's basic IO-tools and of course python won't interpret that file in respect to the format. Furthermore reading like that is text-mode (and maybe binary is required; not sure).

**General rule: if you wrote the solution using a class-method of class model, then read using a class-method of class model too.**

The usage above is normally used to reinstate some state of your model (e.g. MIP-start). If you want to plot it, you will have to do further work. In this case, using python's IO tools might be a good idea and you should respect the format [described here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/sol_format.html). This could be read as csv or manually (and opposed to my remark earlier: it is text-mode; not binary).

So assuming the example from the link is in file `gur.sol`:

```
import csv
with open('gur.sol', newline='\n') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader((line.replace('  ', ' ') for line in csvfile), delimiter=' ')
    next(reader)  # skip header
    sol = {}
    for var, value in reader:
        sol[var] = float(value)
    print(sol)
```

Output:

```
{'z': 0.2, 'x': 1.0, 'y': 0.5}
```

Remarks:

- Code is ugly because python's csv module has some limitations

  - Delimiter is two-spaces in this format and we need to hack the code to read it (as only one character is allowed in this function)
- Code might be tailored to python 3 (what i'm using; probably the next() method will be different in py2)
- [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) would be much much better for this purpose (huge tool with a very good csv_reader)